# How to retrieve hotspot from KRPANO using Javascript

Tags: javascript, krpano

I wan't to retrieve a hotspot from KRPANO using a javascript call.

With the below content I retrieve undefined.

**KRPANO XML snippet:**

```
<hotspot name="spot0" style="hotspot_ani_white" ath="-25" atv="-10" />   
<hotspot name="spot1" style="hotspot_ani_white" ath="-25" atv="-10" />
```

**External javascript file loaded via index.html:**

```
$(function() {

  var krpano = $('#krpanoSWFObject')[0];
  var spotName = 'spot0';
  curSpot = krpano.get(hotspot[spotName]);
  console.log(curSpot)

});
```

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to it. But I'm not sure your can get the element as you wrote it.

First, you should grab the KRPano plugin as an object and not as HTML DOM element:

```
    var myKRPano = $('#krpanoSWFObject'); // First way, no need of "[0]"
    var otherKRPano = document.getElementById("krpanoSWFObject"); // Another way
```

Now you got your JS object, just call "get" method. BUT you should know that "get()" executes internal code: thus you have to place your request as a string! For instance, and with your own code:

```
    var spotname = "spot0";
    var query = "hotspot['"+spotname+"']"; // i.e. "hotspot['spot0']"
    var myHotspot = myKRPano.get(query); // or myKRPano.get("hotspot['spot0']");
```

This will provide you with something like:

```
    Object { _type="hotspot",  DATA={...},  plugin={...},  plus...}
```

From there, you can ask for

```
    > myHotspot.atv
      -10.5868612
    > myHotspot.name
      "spot0"
```

Don't hesitate to use a debug tool for your browser when working with KRPano, as a general advice. Then you can directly try your code and get the issue.
If you do so, you would see that "$('#krpanoSWKObject').get()" is set while "$('#krpanoSWKObject')[0].get()" is not. :)

Regards,

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts and solutions on this question. I was now able to retrieve my 9 coordinates/hotspots and iterating through 9 custom <a> tags in my html template. This was giving me de ability to style does hotspots with css.  This is the end result: https://www.rdmrotterdam.nl/vr-tour/

Comment: Happy to read this! Nice website and nice pano. Good idea to style the HS afterwards! :)

Answer (score 0):

what are you supposed to do by getting the hotspot?

If you need to get some hotspot attribute via javascript you can call a js method in the xml   **< action >** tag and get the attributes directly from the xml hotspot:

> in the javascript file, gets the **ath** and **atv** attributes of a hotspot and
>   returns an array

```
function getspotcoords(ath,atv){
  var spotcoords = [ath,atv];
  return spotcoords
}
```

> in the xml call the function in the **< action />** tag, triggered when click on the hotspot

```
<hotspot name="myhotspot" onclick="myaction"/>

<action name="myaction">

  //js() method is required!
  js(getspotcoords(get(hotspot[0].ath), get(hotspot[0].atv)));

</action>
```

you can get the hotspot itself in the same way, and store it in a variable in the javascriptfile. 
Hope it works!

Comment: Thankyou for your thoughts and solutions on this question. This is the end result. https://www.rdmrotterdam.nl/vr-tour/